# Could not serialize flow execution

Tags: exception, serialization, grails, service, command-objects

**Exception:**

```
Error 500: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in 
           flow or flash scope are serializable
Servlet: grails
URI: /payment.com/grails/payment/makePayment.dispatch
Exception Message: payment.com.ValidationService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d0f2434f 
Caused by: Could not serialize flow execution; make sure all objects stored in 
           flow or flash scope are serializable 
Class: Unknown 
At Line: [-1] 
Code Snippet:
```

**Discussion:**

```
payment.com: project name         
payment: is the name of (domain, view, controller)
makePayment: is a webflow to make payment
ValidationService: is a service to test if credit card is valid or not
```

**Problem:**
i got this error with in my grails project

```
i have a grails webflow that makes a payment, in this webflow i use grails 
command object to validate input values.
when i call the method isValid from Validation service i got this error
```

**Note:**

```
i try to serialize domain class, controller, service, & command object class, 
but i couldn't solve this issue.
```

any help, thanks

**Edit:**

**Validation Service**

```
 package payment.com

 import java.io.Serializable;

 class ValidationService implements Serializable{

// Filter out non-digit characters
def getDigitsOnly (String s) {
  StringBuffer digitsOnly = new StringBuffer ();
  char c;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length (); i++) {
    c = s.charAt (i);
    if (Character.isDigit (c)) digitsOnly.append (c);
  }
  return digitsOnly.toString ();
}

// Perform Luhn check
def isValid (String cardNumber) {
  String digitsOnly = getDigitsOnly (cardNumber);
  int sum = 0;
  int digit = 0;
  int addend = 0;
  boolean timesTwo = false;

  for (int i = digitsOnly.length () - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    digit = Integer.parseInt (digitsOnly.substring (i, i + 1));
    if (timesTwo){
      addend = digit * 2;
      if (addend > 9) addend -= 9;
    }else{
      addend = digit;
    }
    sum += addend;
    timesTwo = !timesTwo;
  }
  int modulus = sum % 10;

  if (modulus == 0){
      return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
}
}
```

**MakePaymentStep1Command**

```
package payment.com

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.Validateable;
import java.io.Serializable;
import payment.com.ValidationService;

@Validateable
class MakePaymentStep1Command implements Serializable{
ValidationService ValidationService
String cardNumber

static constraints ={
    cardNumber(blank:false, size:11..16, validator:{ val, obj->
        if (!obj.ValidationService.isValid(val)){
            return ['payment.cardNumber.invalid']
        }
        return true;
    })
}
 }
```

**Payment Controller**

```
class PaymentController{
....
....
def MakePaymentFlow = {
....
    Step1{
        on('submit').to('Step1Submit')
    }
    Step1Submit{
        action {MakePaymentStep1Command cmd ->
            flow.step1Bean = cmd
            if (!flow.step1Bean.validate()){
                error()
            }
        }
        on('error').to('Step1')
        on('success'){
            flow.message = null
        }.to('Step2')
    }


....
}


}
```

**The Error happens here:**

```
 if (!flow.step1Bean.validate()){
     error()
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a `(src/groovy)` directory in your `grails project`. put your `validation Service class` under this directory, and your `makepaymentStepCommand` will be as:

**`MakePaymentStep1Command`**

```
package payment.com

import java.io.Serializable;
import payment.com.Validation;

class MakePaymentStep1Command implements Serializable{
Validation validation
String cardNumber

static constraints ={
    cardNumber(blank:false, size:11..16, validator:{ val, obj->
         if (!obj.validation.isValid(val)){
            return ['payment.cardNumber.invalid']
         }
         return true;
    })
}
}
```

`I am not sure if this works, but try it.`

Comment: that's fine, it works
but i need to use service to do this work
i use it now, but if you find any way to use service, please mention it
thanks mbayloon

Answer (score 0):

Loking at the exception message, it seems like `ValidationService` is not serializable (though you haven't shown any code, so it's very difficult to guess what might be happening).

At a guess, I'd say this object is dependency-injected into each `Payment`, and you're trying to store a `Payment` in flow scope, which therefore causes an attempt to also store a `PaymentService`.